# Realm dotnet Nested RealmObject PropertyChanged does not fire

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, realm

I bound the PropertyChanged event handler with a method, however, it doesn't fire at all, no matter I am using realm.write() or using ros to modify the properties.

The structure of my models like this: I have a `DeviceList` RealmObject which includes an `IList<Device> Devices` property. And the `Device` RealmObject also has a nested property `People`, while `People` is a RealmObject as well.
When I use `DeviceList.Devices.SubscribeForNotifications()`, everything works fine, changes to properties of `People` in ros will trigger the notification event automatically and correctly. However, `Device.People.PropertyChanged += (do something);` doesn't fire at all, neither the `Device.PropertyChanged += (do something);`, and the UI binding to `Device.People.(Property)` doesn't update as well; but all data in the nested `People` did changed when I used breakpoint to access the data. What is the correct way to get the nested object changes and update the binding UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyChanged` event will only fire for top-level properties on your objects. If a related object changes, e.g.:

```
foo.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
};

foo.Bar.Something = 5; // Doesn't trigger anything
foo.Bar = new Bar(); // Triggers notification
```

Comment: Yes I tried something like `foo.Bar.PropertyChanged`, and `foo.Bar.Something = SomeValue`, but the property changed event still does not fire. I have a `IList<Foo>`, during the `list.Add(foo)` and `foo = new Foo(new Bar())` for loop, I have added `foo.Bar.PropertyChanged`. And `list.SubscribeForNotifications` works fine in the same case.

Comment: I use prism in the same project, and properties in view model are using prism `SetProperty()` to set value, does it matter?

Comment: If you can create a small repro case, feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues. It's a well tested functionality that should work, so it's likely an error with your code, but we can take a look. For example, if you add property change handlers in a loop, it's likely that your objects get garbage collected which will then detach any event handlers.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue of propterties of a nested object not notified of changes.
Any update in this? Do you have a link to the issue on Github?

Comment: The reason was that the OP was letting objects get garbage collected.

Comment: Excuse me... But what do you mean by 'OP'?

Comment: Sorry if that was vague, I meant "Original Poster" i.e. the author of the question.